# After changing ApiName on IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions client still works with Identity Server 4

Tags: asp.net-identity, .net-core, identityserver4

I'm new on Identity Server 4 and I'm following official [QuickStarts](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html).

The doc suggests to play a bit with options, so one can learn how all this is working. But after I tried the last "Further experiments" point i went in trouble.

When i change the ApiName on the API *Startup.cs* file like this:

```
app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
    RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

    ApiName = "api2" //<-- this was api1
});
```

I'm still getting results from the client application (API's IdentityController is executed and it returns the json data of user's claims).

Reading the document (and also maybe according to common logic) I'm led to believe that if the client application obtains a different scope (aka ApiName) compared to that needed by the API, it should not be able to access the controller.

I was wrong on understanding the flow or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also not sure about this, but I think the ApiName is not scope. If you add

AllowedScopes = {"api2"} to the options, then you will get "Forbidden" as the result.

[Check this post](https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/01/new-in-identityserver4-resource-based-configuration/)

Comment: Ty for reply, now it works like a charm! I'm wondering what's the meaning of _ApiName_ property...

Comment: That was a bug. Check this out https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/721